# ESXi 5.1 moving boot USB between hosts

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have two ESXi 5.1 hosts booting from USB sticks.  One host is the production server the second is for testing.  I would like to make some configuration changes in the test box, make sure they work and then move them to production.  The test host is an old AMD box and production is a brand new Intel machine.  Needless to say they are completely different hardware in every respect, except they both boot from a USB stick and they both run the same free version of ESXi 5.1.

What is the best way to move the tested configuration changes to production?

Comment: Implement them and then test them on the test box then implement them and test them on the production box. Why you would want to "migrate" them is a mystery.

Comment: What type of configuration changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* just move the USB drive. But much of that depends on what type of config changes you were making.

The better approach would be to keep track of your configuration changes and apply them to the destination system.